# Convert array of byte to PAnsiChar

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I converted an array of byte named 'TmpData' to PAnsiChar using:

```
PAnsiChar(@TmpData[0]);
```

But some data have line breaks. How do I remove the line breaks? Please see image below

[image: Line breaks]

Comment: So you want to remove all #10 and #13 from TmpData?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note that in the answer below, I am assuming that your byte array is ANSI encoded and zero terminated.*

---

Assign the data to a string:

```
var
  str: string;
....
str := string(PAnsiChar(@TmpData[0]));
```

Then remove the line breaks:

```
str := StringReplace(str, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

You might wish to remove individual `#10` and `#13` characters instead, or remove all whitespace characters. It depends on your needs but the essence is here.

Alternatively you could walk over the byte array removing all bytes that you wish to remove, e.g. with value 10 and 13, or value less than 32. And then cast to `PAnsiChar`.

```
idxDst := 0;
idxSrc := 0;
while TmpData[idxSrc] <> 0 do begin
  if TmpData[idxSrc] >= 32 then begin
    TmpData[idxDst] := TmpData[idxSrc];
    inc(idxDst);
  end;
  inc(idxSrc);
end;
TmpData[idxDst] := 0;
```

Comment: The `PAnsiChar` type-cast, and your loop, both assume that `TmpData` is null-terminated. If that is not the case, you have to take the actual array length into account instead. To assign `TmpData` to a string without a null terminator present, you have to call `SetString()` to copy the `TmpData` data into an `AnsiString` variable first, then you can assign that to your target `string` variable.

Comment: @Remy That assumption is implicit in the question

Comment: There is nothing in the question to indicate whether or not the byte array contains any null bytes.

Comment: @Remy The cast in the question indicates that to me

Comment: Casting a **byte array** to `PAnsiChar` does not guarantee a null terminator is present in the array.

Comment: @Remy No. But it is the common assumption that PAnsiChar is null terminated. That is the convention.

Comment: I agree with Remy. It may be the common assumption, but it doesn't have to be. Since this is apparently an array of byte, you can actually not even be sure about the encoding or that it only contains only one null-terminated string. You only know that the user wants to remove line breaks.

Comment: @Rudy The asker didn't mention any of that, and I just didn't want to try to anticipate every missing detail from the question

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually , the removal of all bytes <32 from the byte array worked.